# How to create a dictionary of closure variable name to value for a closure function. Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

With a python module like:

```
def mult(n):
    a = n-1
    def multn(x):
        b = a
        print (n*x)
    return multn

f = mult(3)
f(4)

print (f.__closure__)
for c in f.__closure__:
    print (c.cell_contents)

print (f.__code__.co_freevars)
```

The output is:

```
12
(<cell at 0x10fd20360: int object at 0x7f8f9bc0b760>, <cell at 0x10fd20398: int object at 0x7f8f9bc0b748>)
2
3
('a', 'n')
```

Is there an easier way or package existing out there, where it creates a dictionary of `clo_var_name` to `clo_val`?

So `{'a': 2, 'n': 3}`

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: You should look at `inspect.getclosurevars`.

Comment: Hmm... they seem to have made a bit of a design mistake with that function. It doesn't have any check for empty closure cells, and it doesn't have a good way to indicate that a closure variable is unbound.

Answer (score 1):

[inspect.getclosurevars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars) will give you a dict of closure-referenced variables.

```
import inspect

inspect.getclosurevars(f)

# returns:

ClosureVars(nonlocals={'a': 2, 'n': 3}, globals={}, builtins={'print': <built-in function print>}, unbound=set())
```